# How does the flutter parent component call a child component?

Tags: dart, flutter

How does the parent component trigger the methods of the child component? How do I trigger the click method of son in fathor? As shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to use callback mechanism to use functions

Comment: How to use callbacks? I am a new flyer, I posted two documents, please help me modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Father extends StatelessWidget {
  var child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    child = son();
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => child?.childFunction(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Son extends StatelessWidget {
  void childFunction() => print('called in child widget');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves your problem but son will be instantiated over and over in the build function. On navigation, on state change, when you hot reload. Make sure not to go against the grain of how flutter apps are "supposed to be built".

Comment: @FilledStacks any suggestion to avoid that?

Comment: @FilledStacks At first I was going to post the answer you did, but then I saw OP wants to go the other way. Dunno why. So I wrote this code and find it odd to work this way.

Comment: @Doc yes. Pass down the state you want in your StatelessWidget from the parent. Depends on what the OP wants to achieve with this functionality. If they're wanting to trigger a call in the child that changes its state that state can be determined by the parent and passed down through the constructor in the build function.

Comment: @Doc you were correct for just answering the question :) I was gonna do that too at first but it's not a good pattern to implement.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you need to use a callback. What this means it that you pass a function to your child that it calls when it needs to. You'll be working from the inside up, not top down.

You'll store the function as a member variable and when your child is clicked you'll call that function. The function will be called in your parent, you can pass whatever data you want back to the parent just like calling a normal function.

Here's some pseudo-code you can use to make the adjustment

```
class son extends StatelessWidget {
  Function onClicked;

  son({this.onClicked});

  Widget build(...) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(...),
      onTap: onClicked
    )
  }
}

class father extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(...) {
    return Container(
      child:son(onClicked: _clicked)
    )
  }

  void _clicked() {
    print('clicked');
  }
}
```

Also, Definitely change your class names to start with a Capital letter.

Comment: Although you have not solved my problem, I feel very much your answer.

Comment: Also using an interface which would be more generic but depends on the requirement. Passing callback is also limited to a direct route, we can further pass the function but changing the state in main class results in ambiguous results.

Comment: i thought OP wanted to call child function from a parent widget? what this does is call a function of the parent widget, not the child.